# Could not expand Zip in react native project

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I have seen the other questions similar to this on StackOverflow, but I feel like this error pops up all the time, and none of the solutions have really lasted for me. I just recently upgraded our project from React Native version 0.34.1 to 0.42.2 (doing the whole `react-native-upgrade` process), so I don't know if that is the cause of all this pain, but I keep getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-awesome-card-io:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library'.
> Could not expand ZIP '/Users/taylorking/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.facebook.fbui.textlayoutbuilder/textlayoutbuilder/1.0.0/29bc8e5a1e2b33944b88277652ee83092ae1dbc0/textlayoutbuilder-1.0.0.aar'.
```

It sometimes happens on that package `react-native-awesome-card-io`, but it could and has happened on any of the packages that the project contains. Sometimes I just keep running `react-native run-android`, and it eventually resolves itself, but it's starting to drive me nuts.

I did just do some snooping around for that specific file, and I wanted to check my permissions on it, and it's showing:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 taylorking  staff  18074 Mar 16 09:41 textlayoutbuilder-1.0.0.aar
```

I'm just not even sure if that is the problem or not? I am not too familiar with gradle, but at least most of the posts on this problem deal with that in some form or fashion. I am willing to share any other information that could help solve this once and for all.

Sorry if this seems to be a duplicate, but nothing else has seemed to be the permanent solution on here.

**Update:**

I just tried deleting that package hoping it would solve my problems, and it just went to the next package with the same error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-camera:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee081Library'.
> Could not expand ZIP '/Users/taylorking/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.facebook.fresco/drawee/0.8.1/a944015ddf50fdad79302e42a85a351633c24472/drawee-0.8.1.aar'.
```

**Update 2:**

I ran `cd android && ./gradlew clean` and it almost finished the cleaning, but it did deny me permission on cleaning the folder related to `react-native-camera` ... the package above. I felt dirty doing this, but I did:

```
sudo ./gradlew clean
```

And that fixed this issue for now ... is there a better, or more long-term solution still? Opinions and thoughts encouraged.

Comment: A gradle clean is often needed so I wouldn't worry about it unless you have to clean the project every time you want to build.

Comment: okay, good to know. and having to sudo to do that for certain packages isn't out of the norm? or is it? @sfratini

Comment: sudo shouldn't be necessary but actually would depend on how you installed it. Let's say you created the RN project in a folder where the normal user does not have access, then you would need sudo to run it. I would try to make sure sudo is not required because that could cover some other potential issue

Comment: True, that's what I thought. I'll have to figure that out. It's legacy code, so I need to figure out how that install happened. Thanks for your help! @sfratini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to recap the solution for the quick scrollers.

`cd android`

`sudo ./gradlew clean`

Or on **Windows**:

`cd android`

`gradlew clean`

Answer (score 0):

Like what @sfratini said in the comments,
Cleaning your gradle is fine every once and a while and it's not a big deal
So, there is no real long-term solution to this problem